# Visual Studio 2017 debugger issues with ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

When I debug **ASP.NET Core** applications in Visual Studio 2017 I can't either preview the content of variables hovering over them or use immediate window or auto/local tabs or the quick watch (I get `Could not evaluate expression`).

I tried both running the app in Kestrel and in IIS Express and I tried enabling `Use Managed Compatibility Mode`.

Doesn't work with .NET Core console app either.

Still no update from Microsoft: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/70835/cannot-preview-variables-aspnet-core.html

Comment: Are you using any addons, like Resharper? Is it still the same when you disable all extensions?

Comment: @Tseng good point, I will try disabling ReSharper and see what happens.

Comment: @Tseng No difference.

Comment: Make sure you aren't running in release build?

Comment: @hellyale definitely Debug, I also created a new console app to test.

Comment: I have Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 and I tried going to Options, then on the left pane Debugging > General and look on the right side to see if any Locals or Call Stack, and I was not able to find them. Can somebody help on this or know what is going on?